# JQuery GET PHP Array on another page via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

Is it possible to get a PHP array created on another page via AJAX? This is what I have so far:

`index.php`

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'array.php', 
   type: 'GET',

   complete: function(data) {
      $('#div').html(data.responseText);
   }
});
```

`array.php`

```
$arr = array('red', 'blue', 'green');
echo $arr; //echo it?
```

As you can see, I'm trying to load `$arr` into a div on index.php. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get it as a PHP array unless you are staying in PHP.  You can get it as an array, however, using json_encode:

`echo json_encode($arr);`

Which can be parsed in javascript.

Use datatype: json (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) or its shortcut, jQuery.getJSON() to read it on the JS side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't echo an array, but you can print_r it for example in the php file being called.